# Comparator with pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers

I have the following comparator but when I use `sort()` it messes up the values of long and the associated sets.

```
bool interestComparator(const map<long,set<long> > * i,const map<long,set<long> > *j)
{

    return (i->size() > j->size());
}
```

How can I rewrite it to sort the map but move each set in the correct position (e.g. if set is associated with long `1`, I would like when I move `1` to move the set as well?

Explanation:

I have:

```
map1 with size 1 set1
map2 with size 2 set2
map3 with size 3 set3
```

The result is:

```
map3 with size 3 set1
map2 with size 2 set2
map1 with size 1 set3
```

but the desired result is:

```
map3 with size 3 and set3
map2 with size 2 and set2
map1 with size 1 and set1
```

Here is the array:

`std::map<long, std::set<long> >  *interestDatePersons[TOTAL_TAGS];`

and I would like to sort this array according to the map size.

Comment: what is the container you are trying to sort? Is it a container of pointers to `map<line,set<long> >` ?

Comment: just an array of `map<long,set<long> >`

Comment: Show us a complete, minimal example of the code which constructs such an array, and does the sorting. It’s completely unclear what you are doing.

Comment: @salamis : In that case, the arguments to the comparator should be `const map<long,set<long> >` (or const references to the map), and not pointers to the map.

Comment: @KonradRudolph please check the array. I would like to sort that array according to the size of the map.

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
return i->size() ? i->size() > j->size() : j->size();
```

Or i messed up with your question.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: I agree with you. So please explain it better.

Comment: and your ternary is wrongly constructed.
It is supposed to be (bool) ? [value/expression for bool is true] : [value/expression for bool is false] .
i->size() is not a bool

Comment: The ternary is fine. `i->size()` will be cast to a bool. Code is equivalent to `if (i->size() != 0) ? (i->size() > j->size()) : (j->size() != 0);`

Comment: So what about sorting the sets first?